# Pandas: How to remove non-alphanumeric columns in Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

A Pandas' Series can contain invalid values:

```
a     b     c     d      e      f     g 
1    ""   "a3"  np.nan  "\n"   "6"   " "
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1, "b":"", "c":"a3", "d":np.nan, "e":"\n", "f":"6", "g":" "}])
row = df.iloc[0]
```

I want to produce a clean Series keeping only the columns that contain a **numeric value** or a **non-empty non-space-only alphanumeric string**:

- `b` should be dropped because it is an empty string;
- `d` because `np.nan`;
- `e` and `g` because space-only strings.

The expected result:

```
a      c     f
1    "a3"   "6"
```

**How can I filter the columns that contain numeric or valid alphanumeric?**

- `row.str.isalnum()` returns `NaN` for `a`, instead of the True I would expect.
- `row.astype(str).str.isalnum()` changes `d`'s `np.nan` to string `"nan"` and later considers it a valid string.
- `row.dropna()` of course drops only `d` (`np.nan`).

I don't see so many other possibilities listed at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html

As a workaround I can loop on the items() checking type and content, and create a new Series from the values I want to keep, but this approach is inefficient (and ugly):

```
for index, value in row.items():
    print (index, value, type(value))


# a 1 <class 'numpy.int64'>
# b  <class 'str'>
# c a3 <class 'str'>
# d nan <class 'numpy.float64'>
# e 
#  <class 'str'>
# f 6 <class 'str'>
# g   <class 'str'>
```

**Is there any boolean filter that can help me to single out the good columns?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings and chain another mask by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with bitwise `AND` - `&`:

```
row = row[row.astype(str).str.isalnum() & row.notna()]
print (row)
a     1
c    a3
f     6
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect, @jezrael. Thank you for your answer. 

I missed the `.notna` that cleaned up the `np.nan`. By the way, why is it necessary to add `.fillna(False)`? The condition `row.astype(str).str.isalnum()` gives the same result without...

Answer (score 2):

you could use a regex

```
row[row.notna() & row.astype(str).str.match('[a-zA-Z0-9]+')]
```

Comment: In my case the coding should take into account also special chars for German and Eastern countries languages, so the match string could become easily quite complex. Thank you anyway for you answer.